# Adjusting NSLayoutConstraint per cell on UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have a UITableViewController, Grouped style, with a custom UITableViewCell. In the UITableViewCell I have NSLayoutConstraints, defined in a storyboard (on the prototype cell), that dictate the size and positioning of a UIImageView. These NSLayoutConstraints are linked to properties of the UITableViewCell subclass.

In the -(void)layoutSubviews method of the subclassed UITableViewCell, I'm attempting to use

```
self.topSpacingConstraint.constant = 0;
```

to change the arrangement on a per-cell basis.

That line of code adjusts the constraint for *all* of my cells, though. I don't understand why, and I don't know how to set the constraint for a single cell.

**Update**

Here's the full code for the `-(void)layoutSubviews` method of the UITableViewCell subclass. `self.topCell` and `self.bottomCell` are properties set by the UITableViewController while configuring the cell. Based on those values, I'm trying to update the AutoLayout spacing of an image on a per-cell basis:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    UIImage *mask;

    if (self.topCell && self.bottomCell) {
        self.imageSpacingTopConstraint.constant = 1;
        self.imageSpacingBottomConstraint.constant = 2;
        mask = MTDContextCreateRoundedMask(self.wineImage.bounds, 6.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0);
    } else if (self.topCell) {
        self.imageSpacingTopConstraint.constant = 1;
        self.imageSpacingBottomConstraint.constant = 0;
        mask = MTDContextCreateRoundedMask(self.wineImage.bounds, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    } else if (self.bottomCell) {
        self.imageSpacingTopConstraint.constant = 0;
        self.imageSpacingBottomConstraint.constant = 2;
        mask = MTDContextCreateRoundedMask(self.wineImage.bounds, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0);
    } else {
        self.imageSpacingTopConstraint.constant = 0;
        self.imageSpacingBottomConstraint.constant = 0;
        mask = MTDContextCreateRoundedMask(self.wineImage.bounds, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    }

    CALayer *layerMask = [CALayer layer];
    layerMask.frame = self.wineImage.bounds;
    layerMask.contents = (id)mask.CGImage;
    self.wineImage.layer.mask = layerMask;
}
```

My need to do this stems from the inconsistent height of cells on the table with Grouped style. The top and bottom cell are 1pt taller than 'middle' cells, while a single cell in the table is 2pts taller. Using the same spacing constraints for the image in all cells results in the image partially obscuring the cell borders for some cells, or leaving whitespace between the image and the border in others.

If anyone can think of an easier way to attack this, I'd appreciate it.

**Solution**

Per the marked solution below, removing the image spacing constraints and then creating new constraints between the image and the cell.contentView did the trick. I removed the code to adjust the constraints from the `-(void)layoutSubviews` method. I added the code to remove and make new constraints to `awakeFromNib` of the UITableViewCell subclass:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    // Since Xcode 4.6.3 creates constrain relationships between the image and the cell, we need to delete and then recreate between the image and the cell.contentView

    [self removeConstraint:self.imageSpacingTopConstraint];
    [self removeConstraint:self.imageSpacingBottomConstraint];

    self.imageSpacingTopConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.wineImage attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
    self.imageSpacingBottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.wineImage attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];

    [self addConstraint:self.imageSpacingTopConstraint];
    [self addConstraint:self.imageSpacingBottomConstraint];
}
```

Comment: Aren't your cells reused? You would have to reset that property in, for example, `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: They are reused, but I'm fairly certain that's not the problem. If I load the table with only three cells, all visible, and only change the prototype value for one of the three, the layout changes in all three cells.

Comment: Please show the full layoutSubviews method.

Comment: I added it inline. Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is you're updating your constraints in `layoutSubviews`, but `layoutSubviews` runs  *after* auto layout.  You should update your constraints in `updateConstraints` instead.

Another problem is Xcode, through at least version 4.6.3, is buggy.  Your image view is a subview of the cell's `contentView`, and constraints **should** be between the image view and the `contentView`.  But in nibs and storyboards, Xcode **incorrectly** sets the constraints between the image view and the cell. (Note: this problem was fixed in Xcode 5 so you probably don't need to worry about it if you are reading this unless you are a time traveler.)

If you poke around in your view hierarchy in the debugger, you'll discover that the cells have varying heights, but their content views all have the same height.  Here are the default sizes:

```
Section Size  Row Position  Cell Height   contentView Height

     1            sole          46              43

     2            first         45              43
     2           second         45              43

     3+           first         45              43
     3+          middle         44              43
     3+           last          45              43
```

Thus when you rely on constraints in your nib/storyboard to position your cell's subviews, you end up with problems.

The simplest solution is to just write code (in your cell's `awakeFromNib`) that deletes the constraints from the nib/storyboard, and creates new constraints between the `contentView` and the image view (and any other subviews of the `contentView`.)  This should eliminate the need to modify the constraint constants based on the cell's position within its section.

Comment: Doing what you described in your last paragraph (deleting and re-creating the constraints to the `contentView` took care of the problem for me. I'll post the code in my `awakeFromNib` in the original post for anyone else who runs into this issue. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

There is no conditionality in your code. Therefore all cells are changed.

Now that you have added the code, there are 2 possible reasons that come to mind:

1. The if statement will never produce a 0 constant if topCell is not `nil`. That does not seem entirely logical.
2. The layer section below the if statement could potentially change the expected layout again.

Comment: I added the full code for `-(void)layoutSubviews`, so you can see the conditionality. Sorry I didn't include that earlier.